# На Android младше 5ой версии перестала отображаться реклама AdMob

Tags: android, admob, реклама

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.onetwo.onetwo"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
compile project(':cropper')}
```

Comment: не факт, что поможет, но не стоит указывать версии библиотеки с плюсом. Указывайте конкретную версию.